# Cant use pip when upgrade python to 3.10 version

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.10

im using `ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and i tried installing `python3.10` and in the end i installed it but when i tried to use pip it gave me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 568, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 886, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 21.2.4 (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==1.5.4'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3243, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3226, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 772, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==1.5.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

i searched it a lot but i couldnt fix it.
thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What package were you trying to install?

Comment: i just typed "pip list" and i get the above result